# Divide a city into regions in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to divide a certain city into several blocks, each representing North, North-West, North-East, South...and so on. I just need the coordinates of the region boundaries (e.g.: North is between X and Y latitude and between Z and T longitude), so that I can check in my app whether a point belongs to a region or another. The regions should not depend on a certain zoom level's boundaries and they don't need to be the same size (maybe the North part of a city is a little bit larger then the South one).

Any idea how can I "draw" these region boundaries? Thank you!

Comment: Unsure the question you're asking, are you looking for the boundary data for the region or actually how to draw the boundaries on the map?

Comment: Both. I would like to draw the boundaries, and then get their coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

For boundary data, you would have to do a search. Depends on the city and country. In the US, many municipalities provide this data directly through a city or country web site. Generally it will be in a GIS data format such as a shapefile. You have a number of different options for working programmatically with GIS data formats. I recommend using the [GDAL libraries](http://gdal.org), 
particularly ogr2ogr. Once you've got the boundary data, you can draw it on the map using [polyline](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines) overlays or create a raster images of the data, say using [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html). Or you can convert the data to KML using ogr2ogr, and upload it to Google Fusion Tables using Google Docs and overlay it using a [FusionTablesLayer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#FusionTables).

Comment: Isn't there something easier? I only need these once, to plot out the regions' coordinates, then I won't be using them...seems to much work for such an insignificant task.

Comment: You could do a search on http://google.com/fusiontables and search for boundary data for your city, someone may have already uploaded them there. Then you can download that as a KML file or just overlay it using a FusionTablesLayer.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any data related to my city. I've ended up drawing some circles and the two bisectrices so that I have the basic regions divided. Then, based on these coordinates and circle radii, I check whether a point belongs to a region or another. Thank you for your answer, though. Will definitely use it when this quick "hack" is not enough.